# SQL Rank and Partition BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am just two days old in SQL. I am trying to update a database wherein i want only those rows to remain in database for each unique identifier for which the serial number (Sl_No.) is highest and inspection_type contains "PMCR".

**Data Snapshot:-**

[image]

**Output Required:-**

[image]

Below is the code i Could write so far.

```
select * from (
            Select Identifier, 
                   Sl_No, 
                   Inspection_Type, 
                   RANK() Over (Partition by Identifier Order By SI_No Desc) AS Rnk
            from copy_of_inspection_response
            where (Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%')
            )
```

**Error I am getting is :-**

[image]

I have tried everything but i am unable to find any solution and not sure as to why is it showing syntax error,

Any help will be highly appreciated !!

Thanks !!

Comment: No need for the subquery, simply do `Select Identifier, ... from copy_of_inspection_response where Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists` as follows:

```
select * from copy_of_inspection_response t
 where t.Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%'
   and not exists 
       (select 1 from copy_of_inspection_response tt
         where tt.Identifier  = t.Identifier 
           and tt.Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%'  
           and tt.SI_No > t.SI_No )
```

If you want to `delete` from the table then use `exists` as follows:

```
delete from t
from copy_of_inspection_response  t
where t.Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%'
   and exists 
       (select 1 from copy_of_inspection_response tt
         where tt.Identifier  = t.Identifier 
           and tt.Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%'  
           and tt.SI_No > t.SI_No )
```

Comment: Come on, we had it as a window aggregate and you rewrote as a self join? What for? All OP needed was an alias

Comment: I was giving the other way of doing the same thing. What is wrong if OP knows how can he achieve the same thing in two different way.

Comment: I know, but really you should explain the downsides of this answer also (extra lookups etc) @ss_0708 Fixed that for you

Comment: @Charlieface _ Thank you so much, that worked for me,

Answer (score 2):

just add an alias at the end of the sub query.

```sql
select * from (
            Select Identifier, 
                   Sl_No, 
                   Inspection_Type, 
                   RANK() Over (Partition by Identifier Order By SI_No Desc) AS Rnk
            from copy_of_inspection_response
            where (Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%')
            ) u
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an Alias after your last ")" will fix the error but won't deliver your expected result. You need to choose one row with highest si_no for each identifier.

Please use below query

```
with cte as (
            Select Identifier, 
                   Sl_No, 
                   Inspection_Type, 
                   Rank() Over (Partition by Identifier Order By SI_No Desc) AS Rnk
            from copy_of_inspection_response
            where (Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%')
            )
select * from cte where Rnk=1
```

To delete all the other rows use below query:

```
with cte as (
                Select Identifier, 
                       Sl_No, 
                       Inspection_Type, 
                       Rank() Over (Partition by Identifier Order By SI_No Desc) AS Rnk
                from copy_of_inspection_response
                where (Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%')
                ) delete cte where Rnk>1
```

Comment: That works , but doesn't delete the not required rows, Can you please help me how to do that within same query

Comment: Added query to delete your desired rows.

Comment: @ss_0708 Please let me know your feedback.

Comment: Yes, That helped, Thanks a lot